# DevHelp php-doc is not available

Tags: php, documentation

I've been using Devhelp but find that it is too much towards python, and Gnome development. Other documentations (such as php-doc) are left out as of now.

Is there a simple way to add php-doc into devhelp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devhelp requires documentation in specific format (.devhelp files, presumably generated with [gtk-doc](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/)), it won't automatically pick documentation from all *-doc packages present on your system.

Edit: PHP documentation is still available in `/usr/share/doc/php-doc/html` once you install `php-doc` package. However, probably more robust solution is to download [PHP documentation in CHM format](http://php.net/download-docs.php) and use it with some CHM viewer like ChmSee or xCHM.

Comment: I'll try to port over the php-doc to devhelp. It can't be that difficult, as its already in html which is used by devhelp internally.

Comment: .devhelp (or .devhelp2) files are basically just TOC of symbols and functions, so this shouldn't be so hard. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using devhelp through synapse for [php-docs](http://php.net/download-docs.php).

Some nice guy wrote a [**script to convert** .CHM into .TGZ (devhelp) format](https://code.google.com/p/htmlhelp/wiki/pyhtmlhelp) and [to install the files](https://code.google.com/p/htmlhelp/wiki/DevHelpInstall). So it goes like:

1. Convert:

   ```
   hhconvert.py YOUR_DOC.chm YOUR_DOC.tgz
   ```
2. Install:

   ```
   devhelp-install YOUR_DOC.tgz
   ```

**Note**

For the convert script to work you need to install first `Python, ctypes, CHMLIB`.

Install puts `YOUR_BOOK.devhelp` and the `res`-Folder into `~/.local/share/devhelp/books/YOUR_BOOK/`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with devhelp, but I'd assume at least the first step would be to install php-doc. It's in the repos, so a quick `apt-get install php-doc` will get it for you. I'd venture to guess that from there, either devhelp will pick it up automatically, or there's a setting somewhere that allows you to specify the location of the php-doc executable. If not, there might be a plugin, but my quick search in the repos only shows php-doc plugins for kdevelop, so you'll probably have to do a Google search for that (the PHP-doc website might also be helpful).

The other alternative, of course, is to see if there's a PHP-oriented alternative to Devhelp.